# Paste path in clipboard modified to be relative to current buffer in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

I'd like to copy a path from the current buffer (or actually any other source) and paste it in to another buffer, but have the path automatically modified to be relative to the location of the target buffer. Does anyone have a script that can do this, or know of a plugin before I try and write my own? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming unnamed register already contains absolute path,

```
:put =fnamemodify(@@, ':.')
```

See also `:h filename-modifiers`. Note that the current working directory and the current file's directory may differ (see `:h 'autochdir'`, `:h :cd` etc.).

Also Vim automatically converts names from buflist / arglist.